# Should i use tinymce or tinyMCE in magento 2.3 and also usage for backward compatible

Tags: magento2, javascript, cms, wysiwyg

From magento 2.3 i see core team integrated new version of tinymce. It's a good thing. Maybe future they will add more editor for magento.

But i have a confuse a bit when to use wysiwyg through below 2.3 version

I found this export in module Magento_Tinymce3

```
var config = {
shim: {
    'Magento_Tinymce3/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src': {
        'exports': 'tinymce'
    }
},
map: {
    '*': {
        'tinymceDeprecated': 'Magento_Tinymce3/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src'
    }
}
};
```

This use tinyme maybe exists in below 2.3. Some files still use this

and this export in Magento_Ui

```
var config = {
shim: {
    'tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min': {
        exports: 'tinyMCE'
    }
},
paths: {
    'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
},
map: {
    '*': {
        --Omit some lines--
        tinymce4:       'tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min',
        wysiwygAdapter: 'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter'
    }
}
};
```

I know magento have implemented dynamic mechanism to load tinymce with config version through backend

Currently things i know is always use 
'**wysiwygAdapter**' for load tinymce instead old way require tinymce